# Swift library bindings to Xamarin

Tags: swift, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I am developing a Xamarin.iOS app. Some functionality is not possible for me to do in Xamarin that I have seen that they are able to do in Swift code.

When searching I came across something called "library bindings" and just want to see if I have understood it correctly.

To my understanding, I would be able to download a SDK to a Xcode project, and through binding use that code in my Xamarin app?

For example: Download Facebook Audience Network SDK to Xcode, bind it to Xamarin and then be able to download ads from my Xamarin code?

Comment: Yes, but there are already bindings available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.iOS/

Comment: @Jason yes I tried that binding but I kept getting "no fill" error  that I have been trying to solve for a week when I loaded an ad. So feels like I need to create a binding of my own

Comment: have you created an issue on the project page?

Comment: @Jason No I haven't, where exactly? Have you implemented facebook ads in Xamarin.ios?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents/tree/main/Facebook.iOS/source/AudienceNetwork